# crc check in a sector of usb pendrive

Tags: usb

I am trying to check for the data integrity in fat32 filesystem.Currently I have implemented fat on lpc2478. For the checking of data integrity, I come to know that each sector of a disk has checksum or CRC.But I wanted to find the location of the CRC in the sector.Can you please advice me on how to find the location of the CRC in a sector of usb pendrive? and will this CRC change with manufacturer of the pendrive.?

Answer (score 0):

While each flash sector on an USB stick usually has a checksum, you can **not** access it over USB. Error checking is handled by the controller on the Sitck itself. It also does some other nice things like wear leveling.

If there is a CRC error then the USB stick will signal a "read failure" error.  See the docs about [USB Mass Storage](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs) on usb.org.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Turbo's answer.

There is no check-sum for a sector of data (usually 512 bytes), visible to the File system. Having said this, you can verify the integrity *not by checking the check-sum for yourself* but by issuing SCSI_VERIFY command that will verify the sector for any defects and report error.

FYI,
Windows Format command issues SCSI_VERIFY to check data integrity before writing the Boot sector.